# How do you manage dependencies during concatenation?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I've been appending all my JS files together and load them in one lump sum so far, and that works great. I've been using grunt to load them. However, one thing I notice is order matters. If I have an inheritance chain such as Entity => Character => Player I need the Entity.js to be loaded first.

How can I control appending order and manage dependencies? Or is this a job for RequireJS?

Comment: Best way for managing dependencies is using AMD.

Comment: If you use grunt-usemin, the files will be concatenated in the order you have them listed in your source.  If what you are doing is as simple as described (concatenating in order) it might be an easy answer.

Answer (score 9):

Use a module bundler, such as [Browserify](http://browserify.org), [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

### With browserify/webpack (or a commonjs loader and requirejs):

**player.js**

```
var Character = require('./character')
function Player() { Character.call(this) }
inherits(Player, Character)
module.exports = Player
```

**character.js**

```
var Entity = require('./entity')
function Character() { Entity.call(this) }
inherits(Character, Entity)
module.exports = Character
```

**entity.js**

```
function Entity() {}
module.exports = Entity
```

**app.js**

```
var Player = require('./player')
var player = new Player()
```

---

### Or if you prefer AMD and requirejs (or using a Browserify/webpack AMD transform):

**player.js**

```
define(['./character'], function(Character) {
  function Player() { Character.call(this) }
  inherits(Player, Character)
  return Player
})
```

**character.js**

```
define(['./entity'], function(Entity) {
  function Character() { Entity.call(this) }
  inherits(Character, Entity)
  return Character
})
```

**entity.js**

```
define(function() {
  function Entity() {}
  return Entity
})
```

**app.js**

```
require(['./player'], function(Player) {
  var player = new Player()
})
```

*It's worth noting here that **webpack** can load modules both sync and async: `var sync = require('./sync')` and `require(['./async'], function(async) {})`.*

Also replace `inherits` with whatever prototypal inheritance method you prefer. I prefer node.js's: http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor or https://npmjs.org/package/inherits

---

### ES6, the next version of javascript, has a spec for a module syntax. So sometime in the future proper module loading will be built into the language. It will likely look something like this:

```
import Character from "character"
function Player() { Character.call(this) }
inherits(Player, Character)
export default = Player
```

There are loaders for webpack and requirejs to load modules in this syntax as well: [ES6 Module Transpiler](https://github.com/square/es6-module-transpiler) (deprecated in favor of [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and [Esperanto](https://github.com/esperantojs/esperanto)) and [es6-loader](https://github.com/shama/es6-module-loader) (deprecated in favor of [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader)).

EDIT: [es6ify](https://github.com/thlorenz/es6ify) now supports the es6 module syntax for use with browserify.

---

In my opinion, concatenating modules is old fashion. Use a module bundler and open the doors to the many wonderful things they provide.

Comment: Great answer. There is also https://github.com/thlorenz/es6ify for using es6 modules with Browserify.

Comment: Unfortunately es6ify doesn't support es6 module syntax: https://github.com/thlorenz/es6ify#unsupported-es6-features

Comment: Hey! This is a great answer. I don't suppose there's a cool way to debug seperate files with Browserify, is there?

Comment: Browserify supports source maps, just enable them with --debug. Or you can compile standalone versions with the --standalone option: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage Also check out https://github.com/chrisdickinson/beefy to compile modules on demand as you visit the page.

Comment: FWIW the latest es6ify does [support es6 module syntax](https://github.com/thlorenz/es6ify#modules) :)